# How to get specific data from input/textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help as a beginner in figuring way to pull specific data that was input via textarea.

Lets say I have textarea that user uses for input of certain data, which simply stores input in a variable. Problem I have is how to pull certain parts of that data (stored in variable now) when there is no set pattern on how data is entered.

For example this could be something user would enter:

***Name:** Random Name*

***Age:** 20*

***Random Number:** 19-12*

***Phone:** 111-111-222*

Now, I understand I could use different methods to fetch data when I know its location in variable or when enter pattern is always same but what if it's different. What if someone writes single digit in Age, Phone format is different or random number is different.

Hopefully I was clear enough with my problem. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask here. HINT: Post CODE, not only text. Right now it sounds like you need several parsers instead of just string manipulation

Comment: Are you saying they can enter each item into any of the field and you're attempting to work out which value is which? If so, that may be a pretty tough problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are pretty sure that user would always make use of a colon (:) after the field, use this code:

```
var data = document.querySelector('textarea').value;
var data2 = data.split('\n');

var name = data2[0].split(':')[1];
var age = data2[1].split(':')[1];
var number = data2[2].split(':')[1];
var phone = data2[3].split(':')[1];
```

Comment: This actually works great especially since yes I can assure that I will always have pretty much same format like: **Name:**  However, only concern I have is that ordering might not always be same?